# Is there is any site to work Microsoft SQL Server live

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Is there is any site to work Microsoft SQL Server 2008 to practise like Oracle Apex?

Thanks,
Vinoth

Comment: You can always install SQL Server Express

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). It has sections to enter DDL and DML statements.

Comment: If u want to practise Stored procedure in Microsoft sql server SQl Fiddle will help me out?

Comment: @user3387033 Yes, you can write SPs in SQL Fiddle

Comment: You can create table and Stored Procedure in the left section and execute the SP in right section.

Comment: Naveen Thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. You can create your schema and execute your queries at [www.sqlfiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: If u want to practise Stored procedure in Microsoft sql server SQl Fiddle will help me out?